# xpages names field selecting directory

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

In Lotus Notes there is a simple way to access the directory from where to select some persons /users from a `names` field: ( this field is having `Use Address dialog for choices` for `Choices` )

[image]

I create a `<xe:namePicker>` to open the ( local ) `names.nsf` from where I can select/add some users:

```
    <xe:namePicker id="namePicker1" for="djTextarea5">
            <xe:this.dataProvider>
                                <xe:dominoNABNamePicker groups="false"
                                    nameList="peopleByLastName" addressBookDb="names.nsf"
                                    addressBookSel="db-name">
                                </xe:dominoNABNamePicker>
            </xe:this.dataProvider>
   </xe:namePicker>
```

Is there any chance I can choose from this `xe:namePicker` the above Lotus Notes places/directories as well in XPages?
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `xe:namePickerAggregator` to add your address books to a list shown as drop down list in name picker:

[image]

```xml
<xe:namePicker id="namePicker1" for="djTextarea5">
    <xe:this.dataProvider>
        <xe:namePickerAggregator>
            <xe:this.dataProviders>
                <xe:dominoNABNamePicker groups="false"
                    nameList="peopleByLastName" addressBookDb="names.nsf"
                    addressBookSel="db-name">
                </xe:dominoNABNamePicker>
                <xe:dominoNABNamePicker groups="false"
                    nameList="peopleByLastName" addressBookDb="namesOther.nsf"
                    addressBookSel="db-name">
                </xe:dominoNABNamePicker>
                ...
            </xe:this.dataProviders>
        </xe:namePickerAggregator>
    </xe:this.dataProvider>
</xe:namePicker>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm using this dataPicker inside a <td>. Should I declared it somewhere? I'm getting the error: It is not defined on tag xp:td.

Comment: You should use it inside your namePicker.

Comment: Thanks. It seems it works, but for the moment I can verify it.. I tried to put a .nsf from other server and it gives me this error: Unable to open database. This server is like this: nameServer/Company ...

Comment: For test: create on your server a copy of your company's address book and give it a different title. Server and database path should always be separated by `!!`.

Comment: Both databases are names.nsf, one it is locally and the other one is on the above described server. I did tried addressBookDb="nameServer/Company!!names.nsf" but still it gives me the error ....

Comment: That should work. Probably, your server has no access to the other server. Are they trusted servers?

Comment: my app is XPiNC. And in NC it works OK, the only problem is when I run it on browser... I think there are some administration settings for the server.

Comment: Don't forget too, that you don't have access to your local address book in browser as code is executed on server.

Comment: So <xe:namePicker id="namePicker1" for="djTextarea5">
      <xe:this.dataProvider>
       <xe:dominoNABNamePicker groups="false"
        nameList="peopleByLastName" addressBookDb="names.nsf"
        addressBookSel="db-name">
       </xe:dominoNABNamePicker>
      </xe:this.dataProvider>
     </xe:namePicker> , I am accessing the local address book?

Comment: I can access the above names.nsf. The error shows when I try to access other names.nsf from other server.

Comment: You get with `addressBookDb="names.nsf"` the database from server if you are accessing from browser.

Comment: And I suppose addressBookDb="names.nsf" is different than the addressBookDb="nameServer/Company!!names.nsf"

Comment: Yes, the latter accesses always server's names.nsf no matter if you are on XPiNC or browser.

Comment: I see. Thanks for your explanations. I will talk with our admin regarding the trusted servers, between the 2 servers, as you said.

Comment: One more issue: So let say I want every user which is logged on, and access this namePicker, to access his ( personal ) address book ( + the company address book )? This isn't possible because the code is executed on server?

Comment: Access to personal address book is only possible for XPiNC. You'd need a copy of personal address book on server for browser access. There is a way to integrate it in user's mail database for iNotes but I don't know if it's possible to use it in this case.

Comment: My app is XPiNC, runs both on Client and Web.

Comment: XPiNC = **XPages in Notes Client** means that it doesn't run on Web(-browser) but in Notes client (= local, **not** on server). You can run an application in XPiNC (= local) *and* browser (= on server).